# В поисках аналогов реализации фрагментов с recycler

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, google-maps-api, recyclerview

В поисках аналогичного решения.
Есть приложение, где в navigation drawer расположены пункты - фрагменты.
По нажатию на каждый из них открывается ***индивидуальный список X*** со своими элементами.
По нажатию на некоторые из элементов, открывается:

- новые списки с элементами(*похоже на recyclerView*).
- google карта с маркерами(для каждого списка разная).
- новые списки с элементами, по нажатию на которые открывается google карта с маркерами(для каждого списка разная).

Вопросы собственно в следующем:

- Стоит ли тут реализовывать фрагмент во фрагменте
- Если списки одинаковые(картинка + текст) то можно реализовать 1 recyclerView с adapter'ом, который просто буду использовать в каждом фрагменте?
- Как в один recyclerView поместить еще один recyclerView?
- Как после выбора категории подменять нажатие на recycler фрагментом Maps?

Answer (score 2):

1. Фрагмент во фрагменте - не очень идея. Старайтесь этого избегать - меньше проблем будет
2. Да, так можно. Но только если данные реально схожи. Не стоит переусложнять адаптер только для того, чтобы он работал для всех возможных случаев. Лучше создайте несколько.
3. Просто поместите ещё один в ячейку другого. Но лучше так не делать - могут проблемы возникнуть. С другой стороны ViewPager/ScrollView внутри ячеек RecyclerView вполне работают.
4. Лучше всего это сделать открыв отдельное активити. Так больше контроля за происходящим и отделение логики.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста чуть поподробней объяснить 3-ий и 4-ый пункт пожалуйста.
В 3-м я так понял вы имели в виду что то https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1622,  не совсем это я имел в виду, по крайней мере не так визуально. Просто как у нас есть список recycler нажимаю на какой то из пунктов его и открывается другие такие же списки.
Что касательно 4-го пункта, опять же, получается по нажатию на элемент в списке recycler я открываю активити, куда еще закидываю свою google map?

Comment: 3. Может вы иммете в виду раскрывающиеся списки? Тогда вам нужен  ExpandableListView или стороннее решение его же через RecyclerView. 4.  Да, новое активити и в нём что угодно, например карта

Comment: в 4-ом пункте получится тогда такая структура Fragment - Recycler - Activiity/Fragment (<include map>)?

Comment: @Inkognito, да, что-то в этом роде.